# Using projections to determine equidistribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, harmonic-analysis

Suppose I have a collection of points on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ I want to know that they are equidistributed (if you want to be more precise, you have a sequence of such collections, and you want to know if they are asymptotically equidistributed, but both the finite and infinite versions are of interest). Here is my test:

Suppose my collection is $P=(x_1, \dots, x_k).$ I look at the set of first coordinates of the $x_i:,$ so $P_1 = (x_{11}, x_{21}, \dotsc)$. Call that set $S_1.$ Now, take a (Haar uniform) random  $M\in SO(n, \mathbb{R}),$ and look at $M(P)_1$ (in words, act by $M$ on $P,$ take the first coordinates of the images). Now, run some test like Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Kuiper on $P_1$ and $M(P)_1,$ which will give some $p$-value $p$ for the two distributions being the same. The question is: how is the $p$-value for $P$ being sampled from a uniform distribution on the sphere related to $p?$

Comment: Are you able to give an indication of the kind of answer you want?

Comment: Wow, a downvote! For what reason?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas If there is probability $1-p$ that the two projections are the same, then there is probability $1-2p$ that the original distribution was uniform would be the sort of answer that would satisfy.

Comment: Sorry - I'm still having problems distilling a question from this. I didn't downvote, but maybe lack of clarity is the reason?